# failing to initialize opencl vector literal

Tags: opencl

So i'm trying to initialize a variable in my opencl host code like this:

```
cl_float2       es = (cl_float2)(0.0f,0.0f);
```

Which, using Clang 2.9, fails with:

```
source/solveEikonalEq.c:75:38: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
cl_float2       es = (cl_float2)(0.0f,0.0f);
                                 ^~~~
source/solveEikonalEq.c:75:26: error: cast to union type from type 'float' not present in union
cl_float2       es = (cl_float2)(0.0f,0.0f);             //ray's tangent vector
                     ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And, when using GCC 4.6.1, fails with:

```
source/solveEikonalEq.c:75:42: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
source/solveEikonalEq.c:75:26: error: cast to union type from type not present in union
```

I'm using AMD's opencl sdk, and can build the examples just fine.
What is it i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use an OpenCL C-style initializer in your host code, which is presumably compiled with a C compiler.  That style of initialization is only valid in your kernels, in other words.  And there, you would not use a platform type, but would instead just use a `float2`.

Try this in your host code instead:

```
cl_float2 var = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

That will work for you.