# How to pass vector parameter to OpenCL kernel in C?

Tags: c, vector, parameter-passing, opencl

I'm having trouble passing a vector type (uint8) parameter to an OpenCL kernel function from the host code in C.

In the host I've got the data in an array:

```
cl_uint dataArr[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
```

(My real data is more than just [1, 8]; this is just for ease of explanation.)

I then transfer the data over to a buffer to be passed to the kernel:

```
cl_mem kernelInputData = clCreateBuffer(context,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uint)*8, dataArr, NULL);
```

Next, I pass this buffer into the kernel:

```
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &kernelInputData);
```

And the kernel function's signature looks something like this:

```
kernel void kernelFunction(constant uint8 *vectorPtr)
```

However, the kernel doesn't seem to be obtaining the correct input data from the pointer to `kernelInputData`. When I pass values back from within the kernel, I see that `vectorPtr` points to something with this structure: `( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ?, ?, ? )` where the question marks are *usually* `4293848814` but sometimes `0`. Either way, not what they're supposed to be.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

I've switched from using an array to cl_uint8 on the host side. I now have:

`cl_uint8 dataVector = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };`

And I pass this vector to the kernel like so:

`clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_uint8), &dataVector);`

And the kernel function's signature looks something like this:

`kernel void kernelFunction(constant uint8 *vectorPtr)`

However, running this code gives me a `CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE` error on `clSetKernelArg()`. This error goes away if I switch the `ARG_SIZE` paramater to `sizeof(cl_uint8 *)` but then I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in `__dynamic_cast` within `clSetKernelArg()`.

My device is:

Apple Macbook Pro (mid-2009)
OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion
NVIDIA GeForce 9400M
OpenCL 1.0
CLH 1.0

Comment: I don't understand, you want to pass one vector or an array of vector ?
'kernel void kernelFunction(constant uint8 *vectorPtr)' please delete the *.

Comment: Just one vector. The last parameter of `clSetKernelArg()` is of type `const void *`.

Comment: `cl_uint8 dataVector = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };`
`clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_uint8), &dataVector);`
and
`kernel void kernelFunction(constant uint8 vectorPtr)`

Comment: Wow. I had thought all kernel function arguments had to be pointers, but apparently not. Your code works beautifully! Edit your answer and I'll mark as correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are defining an array of cl_uint of size 8.
The creation of the cl_mem and the setting of kernel argument are right.
But your kernel argument isn't correct: you try to read an array of cl_uint8 instead of cl_uint.

If you want to use a vector data type, you must declare: cl_uint8 dataArr of size 1. 
Or if you want to use an array of size 8: `kernel void kernelFunction(constant uint *vectorPtr, uint size):`

**Edit:**

The kernel parameter for `cl_uint8 dataVector` is not a pointer.
So, the correct code is:

```
cl_uint8 dataVector = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_uint8), &dataVector);
```

and

```
kernel void kernelFunction(constant uint8 vectorPtr)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I suspected this was the culprit, but I haven't been able to find any examples of creating a vector in the host code. Do you know how to go about this?

Comment: Please, refer to the [opencl specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf) page 198.

Comment: I've already looked at the specs. Like I said, no examples of creating a vector from the host code (like cl_uint8) and populating it with values, as far as I can tell.

Comment: cl_uint8 array;
array.s[0] = 0;
array.s[1] = 1;
array.s[2] = 2;
...
or 

cl_uint8 array = (cl_uint8)(0,1,2,...);

Comment: Ah, not so simple though. I had already tried the `(cl_uint8)(0, 1, 2,...)` construction, which doesn't compile on the host. Your other construction _does_ work, as does the one mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230856/failing-to-initialize-opencl-vector-literal/9234640#9234640), but when I pass such a constructed vector to the kernel with `clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_uint8), &testVector)`, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. This occurs when the arg_size parameter for clSetKernelArg is `sizeof(cl_mem)` and `sizeof(cl_uint *)` as well. What am I missing?

Comment: What is your OpenCL device ? OpenCL version, etc ?

Comment: Apple Macbook Pro 2009, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, OpenCL 1.0, CLH 1.0.

Comment: (Running Mountain Lion, if that helps.)

Comment: It's not a big enough edit to let me make the change, but the `constant` modifier on the kernel function parameter must be changed to `const`, because `constant` can only be applied to a pointer argument. I've a feeling that the lack of `constant` means a lot of slowdown as more memory is allocated, though... do you know if there's a way to pass the data as a pointer after all?

Comment: I'm not sure constant memory is always faster than global memory, it depends of  your device. Private memory is, for a lot of device, in the global memory. If you want the best performance for memory access, local memory will be better.
Please read these links:
-http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/constant.html

-http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/122405/Part-2-OpenCL-Memory-Spaces

Answer (score 1):

**Minimal runnable example**

`int2` is passed to the kernel. It is initially created as an array of `cl_int`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <CL/cl.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *source =
        "__kernel void main(__global int2 *out) {\n"
        "      out[get_global_id(0)]++;\n"
        "}\n";
    cl_command_queue command_queue;
    cl_context context;
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_int input[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    const size_t global_work_size = sizeof(input) / sizeof(cl_int2);
    cl_kernel kernel;
    cl_mem buffer;
    cl_platform_id platform;
    cl_program program;

    clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, &device, NULL);
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, NULL);
    buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(input), &input, NULL);
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &source, NULL, NULL);
    clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, "", NULL, NULL);
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "main", NULL);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &buffer);
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    clFlush(command_queue);
    clFinish(command_queue);
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(input), &input, 0, NULL, NULL);

    assert(input[0] == 1);
    assert(input[1] == 2);
    assert(input[2] == 3);
    assert(input[3] == 4);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Tested on Ubuntu 15.10 OpenCL 1.2 NVIDIA 352.53.